# Is it possible to execute a custom function on the entry crud methods?

Tags: plugin-development, entries

Is it possible to execute a custom function on the entry crud methods? Basically what I want to achieve is that a CP user with certain field value cannot read or save an entry that doesn't have the same field value. (in this case company) Are there any hooks/events available on that level? On group permission level I just want all permissions set to allow on that section.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What i'm interested in (been browsing in the code a but but didn't find anything) is there an event raised after reading or validating the entry? So I can decide last minute to show the entry or not based on custom criteria . Thanks

Comment: EntryRecord is a child of yii's CActiveRecord. Can I just listen for onAfterFind then?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to create a plugin but you could listen for the **entries.saveEntry** event that is noted here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events

Then lookup the value, run validation and even return a custom error message if things were not saved correctly.

Hope this helps.